# LaTeX not rendering properly in title of matplotlib plot

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I have the following code but the title does not render correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.array([0.19641715476064042,
 0.2524989689506581,
 0.3411612727146944,
 0.4232070334074150])

c = np.array([0.17999670292553419,
 0.21057542001074211,
 0.2752899228849294,
 0.36577079519040556])


plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.title('$P(A_i = 0| A_j = 0 \forall j < i)$')

plt.plot(t, '-go', markerfacecolor='w', linestyle= 'dotted', label='n=20')
plt.plot(c, '-bo',  markerfacecolor='w', linestyle= 'dotted', label='n=22')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is an image of what I see from the rendered image. What should I be doing instead?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the "\f"

```
 plt.title('$P(A_i = 0| A_j = 0 \\forall j < i)$')
```

See the double "\"? This causes the "\f" not to be interpreted as a form feed.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a raw string to prevent the `\f` from having a special meaning:

```
plt.title(r'$P(A_i = 0| A_j = 0 \forall j < i)$')
```

Note that the string starts with an `r`, which makes it a raw string.

Comment: A small comment: Use `\mid` instead of `|` for better spacind.